# Different way of handling poison pill

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to handle poison pill scenario with spring-kafka.
currently I'm handling this with below approach, here the failed messages getting pushed to a different topic named `<original-topic>.DLT`.

```
  @Bean
  public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer) {
    return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(deadLetterPublishingRecoverer);
  }
  
  @Bean
  public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer publisher(KafkaTemplate bytesTemplate) {
    return new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(bytesTemplate);
  }
```

So instead of pushing failed message to `<original-topic>.DLT` topic, I want to get it and push it in DB directly.
I tried to get the failed message but no success. can anybody help here. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply implement your own `ConsumerRecordRecoverer` and use it in the error handler instead of the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.

```java
/**
 * A {@link BiConsumer} extension for recovering consumer records.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 2.3
 *
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ConsumerRecordRecoverer extends BiConsumer<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception> {

}
```